# What happened to the Scalaz http module?

Tags: scalaz, scalaz7

I am currenlty reading the book Scala in Action and while reading I'm trying to do the programming exercises. However, I'm stuck now on chapter 6.3 where I have to use Scalaz.

The thing is, the http module of Scalaz 6.0.3 is used. In this chapter I should only be able to do a GET request and later the idea is to build upon the project and make it a little more complex.

The problem I'm facing is that, I'm using Scala 2.11.2, so when I try to use Scalaz 6.0.3, the dependency can not be found. I guess that is because 6.0.3 doesn't support Scala 2.11.2. 
So, I wish to use Scaalaz 7.0.1. However, the HTTP module doesn't exist in 7.0.1, so I can't even compile my project because I have statements like: import scalaz.http._.

Furthermore, in the code, some values like Request object, and Response object are not found because in the example code, as far as I see, they are imported from scalaz.http._.

So, basically, what I'm asking is, can anyone direct me to some kind of tutorial?
Or at least direct me to a changelog where I can see where the objects are now located?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [github](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), when describing the changes in version 7, it explicitly says that

> `scalaz.{http, geo}` dropped.

You can either downgrade to a lower version or use some alternative, as [scalaz-http-client](https://github.com/gpampara/scalaz-http-client) seems to offer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I've seen that the module has been deprecated. I was wondering that maybe they have re-organised the project, but kept the functionalities. Thank you for the link to the alternative, however, it say's that it's a work in progress and it doesn't specify how to include in build.sbt.

Comment: I don't know either, sorry. I think they just imported the source from the version 6 and are working on this. Otherwise find another tool that does the job. I don't know much of scala so I won't be able to help you further.
And for `scalaz.http`, it's not deprecated, it's now been dropped, which means in version 6 it was maybe already deprecated.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find something else then. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer then, and ask another question if you want to know something not asked in your original question.